# Change text-align responsively (with Bootstrap 3)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for a blog. In my custom CSS, I recently added

```
body {
    text-align: justify;
    ...
}
```

I like the result on bigger screens (tablet, desktop). But on small screens (phone), justified text doesn't work very due to the narrower columns plus my blog's occasional use of `long-ish-technical-terms-like-this`.

Can I responsively have `text-align: justify` *only* on bigger screens?

Is it possible to do so solely via CSS, or, would I need to write some custom JS to do so?

Comment: Where’s the actual problem – just put this formatting into an appropriate media query, and you’re done …

Comment: The problem simply is my own ignorance of "media queries" -- I didn't know if/how CSS supported conditionals.

Comment: Not a solution for Bootstrap 3 but there seems to be native support coming in [Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#text-alignment)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, like this (where your breakpoint is set at 48em):

```
body{
    text-align: left;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em){
    body{
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
```

The second rule will override the first if the viewport width is greater than 48em.

Answer (score 124):

Although the provided solution is absolutely right, I think there is a different approach that could be interesting. Bootstrap does not provide alignment classes that depend on window size, but you can define them:

```
.text-justify-xs {
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .text-justify-sm {
        text-align: justify;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .text-justify-md {
        text-align: justify;
    }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .text-justify-lg {
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
```

Then, you could add this classes to your html elements:

```
<body class="text-justify-lg">
```

You can also create css rules for text-left-xx and text-right-xx.

Comment: I like this deeper example and explanation.

Comment: So interesting solution, big like!

Comment: Should it be `text-justify-xs` or `text-xs-justify`? I could be wrong, but I get the impression that Bootstrap names classes by the standard `<group>-[<size>-]<modifier> `.

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23 See [Fred K's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29298245/5199198).

Answer (score 82):

For a more complete solution try this:

```
/*
 * Responsive text aligning
 * http://ohryan.ca/2014/08/14/set-responsive-text-alignment-bootstrap-3/
 */
.text-xs-left { text-align: left; }
.text-xs-right { text-align: right; }
.text-xs-center { text-align: center; }
.text-xs-justify { text-align: justify; }

@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .text-sm-left { text-align: left; }
  .text-sm-right { text-align: right; }
  .text-sm-center { text-align: center; }
  .text-sm-justify { text-align: justify; }
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
  .text-md-left { text-align: left; }
  .text-md-right { text-align: right; }
  .text-md-center { text-align: center; }
  .text-md-justify { text-align: justify; }
}

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
  .text-lg-left { text-align: left; }
  .text-lg-right { text-align: right; }
  .text-lg-center { text-align: center; }
  .text-lg-justify { text-align: justify; }
}
```

Comment: I combined this answer with SASS variables from the media queries in [Alberdigital's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27267067/5199198). The [blog post link](http://ohryan.ca/2014/08/14/set-responsive-text-alignment-bootstrap-3/) in this solution also shows the equivalent in SASS.

Comment: It's worth noting this isn't valid CSS code; this is LESS.

Comment: If you use SASS / SCSS just change the @screen-XX-min to $screen-XX-min and it will work if you are compiling SASS on your gulp/grunt/ or other preprocesor

Answer (score 7):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Eqwf/)

Just resize the window and you can see how it will switch to `text-align:left;` if the window size is less than `400px`.

```
<style>
   @media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
      .text1 {
         text-align: justify;
      }
   }

   p {
      text-align: left;
   }
</style>

<p class="text1">vlédmjd fsdi dlin dsilncds ids nic dsil dsinc dlicidn lcdsn cildcndsli c dsilcdn isa slia sanil sali as as nds nds lcdsicd insd id nid ndi cas sal sa insalic lic sail il dnsailcn lic il eilwnvrur vnrei svfd nvfn vk in f,vn y,h ky,vnkivn iesnvfilsdnhvidsnvdslin dlindilc  ilc lisn asiln sliac lasnl ciasnc in li nsailcn salin ilanclis cliasnc lincls iandlisan dlias casilcn alincalis cli ad lias naslicn aslinc dliasnc slince ineali dliasnc liaslci nasdlicn laincilancfrelvnln dsil cndlic ndlicna linasdlic nsalinc lias</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

I like both Alberdigital and Fred K's answers - former provides valid CSS code you can use in your stylesheets, the latter is more thorough.

Here's the best of both worlds.

```
/*
 * Responsive text aligning
 * http://ohryan.ca/2014/08/14/set-responsive-text-alignment-bootstrap-3/
 *
 * EDITED by Nino Škopac for StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/18602121/1325575)
 */
.text-xs-left { text-align: left; }
.text-xs-right { text-align: right; }
.text-xs-center { text-align: center; }
.text-xs-justify { text-align: justify; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .text-sm-left { text-align: left; }
    .text-sm-right { text-align: right; }
    .text-sm-center { text-align: center; }
    .text-sm-justify { text-align: justify; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .text-md-left { text-align: left; }
    .text-md-right { text-align: right; }
    .text-md-center { text-align: center; }
    .text-md-justify { text-align: justify; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .text-lg-left { text-align: left; }
    .text-lg-right { text-align: right; }
    .text-lg-center { text-align: center; }
    .text-lg-justify { text-align: justify; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case i dont like media queries overuse. So, sometimes i repeat the content in two ways. One custom aligned and the other default aligned. Some code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <%-- Some content here --%>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-6 text-right hidden-xs">
    <%-- Same content here --%>
</div>
```

This might be usefull in some cases, depends on what you are doing but Keep in mind that is not a good idea to repeat large contents of HTML, this solution might be used for small cases only.

Comment: This is a bad idea!

Comment: @LuizGonçalves, why? we I criticize something, I would mention why.

Comment: Doing this you must pass the content twice! This is SEO-unfriendly and increases page size, forcing the server to provide content twice. You can make in many othes betters ways, like our friends explained in the others answers.

Comment: Yeah, its not the best solution. But i could work in some cases. Depens on what you are doing. I am editing to clear that point.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried col-auto and mr-auto?
Further info: [Margin utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)
With the move to flexbox in v4, you can use margin utilities like .mr-auto to force sibling columns away from one another.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-auto mr-auto">
        <p>Blah</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-auto">
        <p>Blah</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It works for me, try this:

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```

Answer (score -6):

All the "text-align" classes are provided in Bootstrap : Simply use `align-lg-left`, `align-xs-center`, etc ...

Comment: This isn't a feature of Bootstrap as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've actually sought `align-lg-left` in latest bootstrap CSS file, and it's not there.