# How can I align text center on small screens with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I have html as:-

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-left">
            <p>
                &copy; 2015 example.com. All rights reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-right">
            <p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

From the code you can see that the column's text are left and right aligned respectively. However in the xs mode I like them to be center aligned. How can I do this using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602121/change-text-align-responsively-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21698

Answer (score 90):

Responsive text alignment has been added in Bootstrap V4:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment

> For left, right, and center alignment, responsive classes are available that use the same viewport width breakpoints as the grid system.

```
<p class="text-sm-left">Left aligned text on viewports sized SM (small) or wider.</p>
```

Comment: But they didn't add support for responsive justified text into their system. When using justified text, you typically do not want it on for small and xs, but you do for medium+. You may be tempted to right it as:  

    <p class="text-xs-left text-justify">Content</p>  

However, the style rule for `text-xs-left` is 

    .text-xs-left {
        text-align: left !important;
    }  

The use of `!important trounces on the justify command even though `text-justify` has the `!important` flag as well. The fact that `text-xs-left` is in a media query causes it to have greater specificity.

Answer (score 34):

```
<div class="text-lg-right text-center">
  center in xs and right in lg devices
</div>
```

`text-lg-right` applies for large size only, so except large size `text-center` will be applied for the rest of the sizes.

Answer (score 23):

There is nothing built into bootstrap for this, but some simple css could fix it. Something like this should work. Not tested though

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .col-xs-12.text-right, .col-xs-12.text-left {
              text-align: center;
       } 
    }
```

Comment: I had to add !important for this fix to work as Bootstrap had text-left!important.

Comment: It feels rather confusing to overwrite the CSS classes only for mobile. It more error prone like this however it will work!

Answer (score 19):

Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 text-md-left text-center">md left, xs center</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 text-md-right text-center">md right, xs center</div>
```

Comment: Classes should be listed smallest to largest per convention and Bootstrap's "mobile first" philosophy, as well as to match their actual cascade.

Answer (score 15):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    footer .text-right, 
    footer .text-left {
        text-align: center;
    } 
}
```

I updated @loddn's answer, making two changes

- `max-width` of `xs` screens in bootstrap is 767px (768px is the start of `sm` screens)
- (this one is a matter of preference) I used `footer` instead of `col-*` so that if the column widths change, the CSS doesn't need to be updated.

Answer (score 14):

Css Part is:

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

  // Align text to center.
  .text-xs-center {
    text-align: center;
  } 
}
```

And the HTML part will be ( this text center work only below 767px width )

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-right text-xs-center">
        <p>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the most elegant answer as it doesn't hack the existing classes but adds a new, meaningful one.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Bootstrap uses the mobile first principle. A media query with max-width doesn't follow this simple principle. It should be something like, text-center with an combination of text-sm-right. Always text center, and from sm devices a right position

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap is mobile-first. That doesn't mean you can't customize in small ways using an inverted approach. Nothing gets broken by doing so.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who is looking for the solution using Bootstrap 5:

```
<p class="text-center text-md-start">
```

There is a small change between Boostrap4 and Boostrap5, more in the link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 5, `-left` and `-right` have been replaced with `-start` and `-end` respectively.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/

Answer (score 1):

This was tagged as a bootstrap 3, but maybe this will be helpful:
In Bootstrap 4.0.0 (non beta) :
Inside the col class, use

```
<div class="col text-center text-md-left">
```

"text-center" centers the text for all window sizes, then adding the "text-md-left" or "text-md-right" to change it above sm.  You could make it "text-sm-left", "text-lg-left" or whatever.  But having it set to center always first sets up it up.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center text-md-left">
        <p>
          &copy; 2015 example.com. All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center text-md-right">
        <p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>

</footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bs3-upgrade library for spacings and text aligment...

https://github.com/studija/bs3-upgrade

> **col-xs-text-center col-sm-text-left**
>
> **col-xs-text-center col-sm-text-right**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-text-center col-sm-text-left">
            <p>
                &copy; 2015 example.com. All rights reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-text-center col-sm-text-right">
            <p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap version Bootstrap v5, you'll not find `text-lg-left` or `text-md-right`.

`-left` and `-right` has been updated with `-start` and `-end`

```
<div class="text-center text-sm-center text-md-start text-lg-end">
  <p>text-center: for <576px</p>
  <p>text-sm-center: for ≥576px</p>
  <p>text-md-start: for ≥768px</p>  < for left align
  <p>text-lg-end: for ≥992px</p>  < for right align
</div>
```